# How to stop Tkinter from freezing from while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a GUI for my code. Every time something new is copied to the clipboard it will search up those sold listings on ebay. I want my code to always run the ebay function every time something is copied. The issue I am having is that I want to have an off button that kills that function so I can keep the GUI open and toggle it on and off as I please. I have tried threading, root.after and several other things to try and fix my code but every time the on button is pressed my GUI still freezes. What am I doing wrong/ how can I have the GUI stay functioning while always searching for a new value from the clipboard?

```
import threading
import sys
import os
import webbrowser
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("SO_site-packages"))
import pyperclip
import tkinter as tk

run = True

def ebay():
    current=""
    while run == True:
        new = pyperclip.paste()

        if new != current:
            current = new
            webbrowser.open('https://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + str(new) + '&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&LH_ItemCondition=3000')


thread = threading.Thread()
thread.start()


def switchon():
    global run
    run = True
    ebay()

def switchoff():
    global run
    run = False

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("EbayPaste")
    root.geometry('400x300')
    onbutton = tk.Button(root, text="ON", command=switchon)
    onbutton.pack()
    offbutton = tk.Button(root, text="OFF", command=switchoff)
    offbutton.pack()

    root.mainloop()

thread2 =threading.Thread
thread2.start(main())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `threading.Thread()` is not quite correct, as it has no valid target. Also, I'm not sure why you want to start/stop the program so in my solution I have taken that functionality out (although if you *REALLY* wanted to you could figure out a way to get it). The drastically simplified code that does what I *think* you are trying to accomplish (search on ebay everything you have in the clipboard):

```
import threading
import sys
import os
import webbrowser
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("SO_site-packages"))
import pyperclip
import tkinter as tk


def ebay():
    current = ""
    new = pyperclip.paste()
    if new != current:
        current = new
        webbrowser.open('https://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + str(new) + '&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&LH_ItemCondition=3000')


def open_ebay():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=ebay)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("EbayPaste")
    root.geometry('400x300')
    tk.Button(root, text="load ebay from clipboard", command=open_ebay).pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**@EDIT**

OK I think this will get what you were looking for. You will need to install selenium for which I will refer you to https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

```
import threading
import pyperclip
import tkinter as tk
import time
from selenium import webdriver


class myGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread_running = bool
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("EbayPaste")
        self.win.geometry('400x300')
        tk.Button(self.win, text="load ebay from clipboard", command=self.start_thread).pack()
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Stop thread", command=self.close_thread).pack()

    def close_thread(self):
        self.thread_running = False

    def start_thread(self):
        self.thread_running = True
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.ebay)
        thread.start()

    def ebay(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        old = ""
        loop = 0
        while self.thread_running:
            print('running loop {}'.format(loop))
            loop += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            new = pyperclip.paste()
            if new != old:
                old = new
                self.driver.get('https://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + str(new) + '&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&LH_ItemCondition=3000')
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = myGUI()
    app.win.mainloop()
```

This will spawn a thread and every 1 second check your clipboard for changes. If there is a change, it will pull it up in the browser that it spawns in. When the user turns off the thread, the browser will close itself automatically. Through this method the GUI does not freeze! If this helped solve your problem it'd be great if you could click that check mark by the post to accept the answer. If you *REALLY* liked it you could give it a +vote as well :D

Comment: The reason I want to toggle it on and off is because when I click the On button the function will search in Ebay by pasting from the clipboard. When that function is running it will search for a new value from the clipboard and if there is one it will search the new value. I want to be able to toggle it off so it stops searching for the new clipboard value. In the code you provided you have to click the button every time you copy something new to your clipboard

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that you replied! This works exactly how I wanted it to, thank you! I replaced the self.driver.get with the webbrowser.open and it works the same as originally but is much quicker  and opens multiple tabs which I prefere. So it works with selenium and webbrowser!